# How to dismiss a Tab Bar Controller from inside one of its own tabs?

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uitabbarcontroller, dismiss

I am building a new app. My auth flow presents a tab bar controller with 5 tabs at the end.

In my login screen, it presents the tab bar controller after successful login:

```
let vc = MainTabBarVC()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self?.present(vc, animated: true)
```

On the tab bar controller, inside the last tab (My Settings VC), there is a log-out button. How can I dismiss the tab bar entirely with this log-out button's action and return to the login screen? I am trying to dismiss the entire tab bar controller from inside one of its tab.

Comment: Rather than presenting the tab bar controller modally, you should set it as the root view controller for your window/scene. Then your logout button would change the root view controller back to the "logged out" view controller

Comment: The approach I would take is to make the tab bar controller the app's root view controller. If the user needs to login then you present the login screen from the tab bar controller. Upon successful login your dismiss the login screen. When the user chooses to log out, you simply present the login screen again (over the tab bar controller). No need to ever change the app's root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

Thanks to @Paul and @HangarRash for comments. As @Paul told me in the comments, I changed the root view controller, and it worked perfectly. My code:

```
        let vc = LoginVC(authManager: authManager)
        
        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate {
            guard let window = delegate.window else { return }
            UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                window.rootViewController = vc
                window.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }, completion: { completed in
                // Something maybe later
            })
        }
```